# NSManagedObject and protocol conformance

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, nsmanagedobject

Here is my problem, I have an type (*MyManObj*) which is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

This type has two fields: *fieldOne*,*fieldTwo*:`Int16`

I also have a protocol defined this way:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    var fieldOne:Int16 {get set}
    var fieldTwo:Int16 {get set}
}
```

**I need to express the fact that *MyManObj* conforms to *MyProtocol*. And I don't know how to do it.**

I have tried to add code like this, but it does not work:

```
extension MyManObj:MyProtocol {}
```

Precisely I get this message:

```
Type 'MyManObj' does not conform to protocol 'MyProtocol'.
```

I have then tried a few more variations, but with no interest because they failed.

Comment: what about class MyManObj: NSManagedObject ,MyProtocol {} ?

Comment: Don't tell us “But it does not work.” Copy what the compiler says and paste it into your post.

Comment: OK. Hoping that may be useful, I have added some information at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the variables/ properties in your protocol are not marked optional [i.e. they are required] and your compiler is asking you to implement all the method/ properties declared in your protocol.

To resolve this issue you can do:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol: class {
     optional var fieldOne:Int16 {get set}
     optional var fieldTwo:Int16 {get set}
 }
```

*OR*

```
extension MyManObj:MyProtocol {
    var fieldOne:Int16 {
        get{}
        set{}
    }
    var fieldTwo:Int16 {
        get{}
        set{}
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, @Rahim Khalid. Thank you for your two suggestions, but the first one is not good for me, because I need the variables so they cannot be optional. I have tried the second one and I get the error message: "Invalid redeclaration of 'fieldOne'".

Comment: have you already have variable name as fieldOne in your class(MyManObj) ?

Comment: Yes, this is written on the second line of my post.